# How to read attributes of xml tags in groovy Jenkins pipeline

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="xray" tests="2" failure="0" timestamp="2023-07-07T05:25:33.339Z" skipped="0" failure-evaluating="0">
    <testcase name="SPT-4323" classname="testim.io.test" time="52.597" ownedBy="Staysure Automation" ownerEmail="automationteam@staysure.co.uk">
      <system-out>https://app.testim.io/#/project/9GScC/branch/master/test/ZKkR</system-out>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="SPT-4331" classname="testim.io.test" time="20.823" ownedBy="Automation Team" ownerEmail="nipunam@intervest.lk">
      <system-out>https://app.testim.io/#/project/9GScCU/branch/master/test/7O9a</system-out>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Is there a way to get values of name attributes in each testcase tag to an array in the Jenkins pipeline groovy script (This XML can have different number of "testcase" tags).

Example Array:
Test_IDS : ["SPT-4323", "SPT-4331"]

I've tried as follows and its not printing any value

```
def File = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/testim-tests-report.xml"
echo "${File}"
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(File)
def xrayID = xml.testsuites.testsuite.testcase[1].@name

echo "Xray ID is ${xrayID}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("""
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="xray" tests="2" failure="0" timestamp="2023-07-07T05:25:33.339Z" skipped="0" failure-evaluating="0">
    <testcase name="SPT-4323" classname="testim.io.test" time="52.597" ownedBy="Staysure Automation" ownerEmail="automationteam@staysure.co.uk">
      <system-out>https://app.testim.io/#/project/9GScC/branch/master/test/ZKkR</system-out>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="SPT-4331" classname="testim.io.test" time="20.823" ownedBy="Automation Team" ownerEmail="nipunam@intervest.lk">
      <system-out>https://app.testim.io/#/project/9GScCU/branch/master/test/7O9a</system-out>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
""")

def xrayIDs = xml.testsuite.testcase.collect { it.@name }

println "Xray IDs are ${xrayIDs}"
```

Here will be your array in the output:

```
Xray IDs are [SPT-4323, SPT-4331]
```

You did almost everything correct, you just missed that xml parser sees root tag as a root element of the path, so you shouldn't mention it in the path: your `xml.testsuites.testsuite` should look like `xml.testsuite`

I hope it helps.